# Casting an Array of Integers into a Long

Tags: java, arrays, casting, integer

I am trying to typecast an integer array into a long array, but I don't quite know how to go about doing this.

So far, my code looks like this:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class main {

public static int[] sect(){
    int[] returned = new int[4];
    Random rand = new Random();
    returned[0] = 4;
    returned[1] = rand.nextInt(8) + 1;
    returned[2] = rand.nextInt(7) + 1;
    returned[3] = rand.nextInt(6) + 1;

    return returned;
}

public static String num(){
    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
        int[] ints = sect();
        for(int i =0; i < ints.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(ints[i]);
        }
    }
    return null;
}
}
```

I have tried doing things like:

```
return ((long)num());
```

But that never works.  Does anyone know how I would go about doing this?

Comment: You can't cast an array of primitives into one primitive.  What operations do you want to do to the `int`s to transform them into a `long`?

Comment: if you need an array of longs define one....

Comment: ok, i'll try that.  Thanks

Comment: You'd better use `Main` not `main` as a class name .

Comment: The method `num()` returns a `String` - and you can't cast a `String` to a `long`.

Comment: @Jason It doesn't really return anything.

Comment: *Does anyone know how I would go about doing this?* Doing what? You haven't explained what you're trying to do.

Comment: Unaccepting an answer is perfectly fine, but I would ask you to at least consider upvoting those answer(s) you deem helpful to you. You can accept only one answer, but upvote as much as you want to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using Java 8, if so this will work:

```
int[] arrayOfIntegers = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};

long[] arrayOfLongs = Arrays.stream(arrayOfIntegers).mapToLong(i -> i).toArray();
```

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#asLongStream--

Comment: @GhostCat I don't think you can use `System.arraycopy()` with different array types.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that.

You simply have to create an equal sized array, and copy the int values into that array. Unfortunately System.arraycopy() can not do that for you... So you can't avoid the manual copying here.

Because an array of int isn't an array of longs. Therefore there is no such cast as from a single int into a single long.